# License Issue when Watson Studio Academic Trial Installed

Tags: spss-modeler, watson-studio

I have a problem with Modeler activation. I have evaluated Trial version now I want to use as Academic Purpose. But it asks for need deactivation of the product first.

In myibm dashboard in Manage Page, there is no menus for activated devices so I can not deactivate previous one.

Can you please help to activate products and Use IBM Modeler

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that it is not possible using the same account for an already expired trial unless you purchase. Maybe, for this purpose, you need to create an account using your academic email.

Regards,